# Проверить содержится ли в коллекции конкретный тип данных

Tags: java

Допустим есть коллекция, пускай будет Arraylist list и в ней содержатся элементы разных типов. Есть ли возможность проверить содержится ли какой-то конкретный тип в list? Что-то типа contains по типу?

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно написать что-то типа такого:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(3);
        list.add("hi");
        list.add('w');
        list.forEach(new Consumer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Object o) {
                if (o instanceof Integer) {
                    System.out.println(o);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Но, честно говоря, все это смахивает на один большой костыль.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("ds");
    list.add(7);
    list.add(true);
    System.out.println(containsType(list, String.class)); //true
    System.out.println(containsType(list, Long.class));   //false
}

static <T> boolean containsType(List list, Class<T> type) {
    for (Object o : list) {
        if (type.isInstance(o)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```